# STM32H723 - Problem with Serial RAM in memory mapped mode

Tags: ram, stm32h7

I’m testing a 32Mb serial QUAD SPI RAM (ISSI – ISS66WVS4M8) with the nucleo – H723ZG development board.
It works fine if I use all the QUAD SPI commands but my need is to use it in memory mapped mode.
When i use the memory mapped mode configuration I notice a problem in the write phase.
The test that I’m doing consists in writing a sector of the memory and then reading it, checking that both operations are fine.
So, after having set the memory mapped configuration, I try to write with a for cycle 128 values inside the memory.
Here is the strange thing: if these 128 values that I try to write are a “uint64_t”  type the write operation works fine.
But if I use “uint8_t” or uint32_t”  type, write operation don’t work and some of the values read in the memory are not correct.
I also have noticed that with the 64bit variable, the “CHIP SELECT” signal is correctly set low at the beginning of the operation and set high just at the end of the whole operation, while with the 32 o 8 bit variable CS goes low and high several times.

Do you have any suggesions? I put here the code

```
#include "main.h"
#include "usb_device.h"



I2C_HandleTypeDef hi2c1;

OSPI_HandleTypeDef hospi1;

SPI_HandleTypeDef hspi1;

UART_HandleTypeDef huart5;
UART_HandleTypeDef huart3;

//uint64_t buffer[128], dato;
//uint32_t buffer[128], dato;
uint8_t buffer[128], dato;


void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_USART3_UART_Init(void);
static void MX_I2C1_Init(void);
static void MX_OCTOSPI1_Init(void);
static void MX_SPI1_Init(void);
static void MX_UART5_Init(void);

int main(void)
{

  OSPI_RegularCmdTypeDef sCommand;
  OSPI_MemoryMappedTypeDef sMemMappedCfg;
  uint32_t address = 0x00;
  uint8_t index;
  __IO uint8_t step = 0;
  __IO uint8_t *mem_addr = (__IO uint8_t *)(0x90000000);
//  __IO uint32_t *mem_addr = (__IO uint32_t *)(0x90000000);
//  __IO uint64_t *mem_addr = (__IO uint64_t *)(0x90000000);
  uint8_t reg[8];

  SCB_EnableDCache();
  HAL_Init();
  SystemClock_Config();
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART3_UART_Init();
  MX_I2C1_Init();
  MX_OCTOSPI1_Init();
  MX_SPI1_Init();
  MX_UART5_Init();
  MX_USB_DEVICE_Init();
 


  /* PSRAM: QSPI Mode Disable        ------------------------------------- */

    sCommand.OperationType      = HAL_OSPI_OPTYPE_COMMON_CFG;
    sCommand.FlashId            = HAL_OSPI_FLASH_ID_1;
    sCommand.Instruction        = OSPI_QUADMODE_DISABLE;
    sCommand.InstructionMode    = HAL_OSPI_INSTRUCTION_4_LINES;
    sCommand.InstructionSize    = HAL_OSPI_INSTRUCTION_8_BITS;
    sCommand.InstructionDtrMode = HAL_OSPI_INSTRUCTION_DTR_DISABLE;
    sCommand.Address            = 0x0;
    sCommand.AddressMode        = HAL_OSPI_ADDRESS_NONE;
    sCommand.AddressSize        = HAL_OSPI_ADDRESS_24_BITS;
    sCommand.AddressDtrMode     = HAL_OSPI_ADDRESS_DTR_DISABLE;
    sCommand.AlternateBytesMode = HAL_OSPI_ALTERNATE_BYTES_NONE;
    sCommand.DataMode           = HAL_OSPI_DATA_NONE;
    sCommand.DataDtrMode        = HAL_OSPI_DATA_DTR_DISABLE;
    sCommand.DummyCycles        = 0;
    sCommand.DQSMode            = HAL_OSPI_DQS_DISABLE;
    sCommand.SIOOMode           = HAL_OSPI_SIOO_INST_EVERY_CMD;
    if (HAL_OSPI_Command(&hospi1, &sCommand, HAL_OSPI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE) != HAL_OK)
    {
      Error_Handler();
    }

  /* PSRAM: Reset CMD        ------------------------------------- */

  sCommand.OperationType      = HAL_OSPI_OPTYPE_COMMON_CFG;
  sCommand.FlashId            = HAL_OSPI_FLASH_ID_1;
  sCommand.Instruction        = OSPI_RESET_ENABLE;
  sCommand.InstructionMode    = HAL_OSPI_INSTRUCTION_1_LINE;
  sCommand.InstructionSize    = HAL_OSPI_INSTRUCTION_8_BITS;
  sCommand.InstructionDtrMode = HAL_OSPI_INSTRUCTION_DTR_DISABLE;
  sCommand.Address            = 0x0;
  sCommand.AddressMode        = HAL_OSPI_ADDRESS_NONE;
  sCommand.AddressSize        = HAL_OSPI_ADDRESS_24_BITS;
  sCommand.AddressDtrMode     = HAL_OSPI_ADDRESS_DTR_DISABLE;
  sCommand.AlternateBytesMode = HAL_OSPI_ALTERNATE_BYTES_NONE;
  sCommand.DataMode           = HAL_OSPI_DATA_NONE;
  sCommand.DataDtrMode        = HAL_OSPI_DATA_DTR_DISABLE;
  sCommand.DummyCycles        = 0;
  sCommand.DQSMode            = HAL_OSPI_DQS_DISABLE;
  sCommand.SIOOMode           = HAL_OSPI_SIOO_INST_EVERY_CMD;
  if (HAL_OSPI_Command(&hospi1, &sCommand, HAL_OSPI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  HAL_Delay(1);

  sCommand.Instruction        = OSPI_RESET_CMD;
  if (HAL_OSPI_Command(&hospi1, &sCommand, HAL_OSPI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  HAL_Delay(1);

  /* PSRAM: Read ID         ------------------------------------- */
  sCommand.OperationType      = HAL_OSPI_OPTYPE_COMMON_CFG;
  sCommand.FlashId            = HAL_OSPI_FLASH_ID_1;
  sCommand.Instruction        = OSPI_READ_ID;
  sCommand.InstructionMode    = HAL_OSPI_INSTRUCTION_1_LINE;
  sCommand.InstructionSize    = HAL_OSPI_INSTRUCTION_8_BITS;
  sCommand.InstructionDtrMode = HAL_OSPI_INSTRUCTION_DTR_DISABLE;
  sCommand.Address            = 0x0;
  sCommand.AddressMode        = HAL_OSPI_ADDRESS_1_LINE;
  sCommand.AddressSize        = HAL_OSPI_ADDRESS_24_BITS;
  sCommand.AddressDtrMode     = HAL_OSPI_ADDRESS_DTR_DISABLE;
  sCommand.AlternateBytesMode = HAL_OSPI_ALTERNATE_BYTES_NONE;
  sCommand.DataMode           = HAL_OSPI_DATA_1_LINE;
  sCommand.DataDtrMode        = HAL_OSPI_DATA_DTR_DISABLE;
  sCommand.DummyCycles        = 0;
  sCommand.DQSMode            = HAL_OSPI_DQS_DISABLE;
  sCommand.SIOOMode           = HAL_OSPI_SIOO_INST_EVERY_CMD;
  sCommand.NbData             = 8;
  if (HAL_OSPI_Command(&hospi1, &sCommand, HAL_OSPI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  if (HAL_OSPI_Receive(&hospi1, reg, HAL_OSPI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }


  /* PSRAM: Enter Quad mode ------------------------------------- */

  sCommand.OperationType = HAL_OSPI_OPTYPE_COMMON_CFG;
  sCommand.FlashId = HAL_OSPI_FLASH_ID_1;
  sCommand.Instruction = OSPI_QUADMODE_CMD;
  sCommand.InstructionMode = HAL_OSPI_INSTRUCTION_1_LINE;
  sCommand.InstructionSize = HAL_OSPI_INSTRUCTION_8_BITS;
  sCommand.InstructionDtrMode = HAL_OSPI_INSTRUCTION_DTR_DISABLE;
  sCommand.AddressMode = HAL_OSPI_ADDRESS_NONE;
  sCommand.AlternateBytesMode = HAL_OSPI_ALTERNATE_BYTES_NONE;
  sCommand.DataMode = HAL_OSPI_DATA_NONE;
  sCommand.DummyCycles = 0;
  sCommand.DQSMode = HAL_OSPI_DQS_DISABLE;
  sCommand.SIOOMode = HAL_OSPI_SIOO_INST_EVERY_CMD;

  /*Enter QUAD mode*/

  if (HAL_OSPI_Command(&hospi1, &sCommand, HAL_OSPI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE) != HAL_OK)
  {
  Error_Handler();
  }

  sCommand.FlashId            = HAL_OSPI_FLASH_ID_1;
       sCommand.InstructionMode    = HAL_OSPI_INSTRUCTION_4_LINES;
       sCommand.InstructionSize    = HAL_OSPI_INSTRUCTION_8_BITS;
       sCommand.InstructionDtrMode = HAL_OSPI_INSTRUCTION_DTR_DISABLE;
       sCommand.AddressMode        = HAL_OSPI_ADDRESS_4_LINES;
       sCommand.AddressSize        = HAL_OSPI_ADDRESS_24_BITS;
       sCommand.AddressDtrMode     = HAL_OSPI_ADDRESS_DTR_DISABLE;
       sCommand.AlternateBytesMode = HAL_OSPI_ALTERNATE_BYTES_NONE;
       sCommand.DataMode           = HAL_OSPI_DATA_4_LINES;
       sCommand.DataDtrMode        = HAL_OSPI_DATA_DTR_DISABLE;
       sCommand.SIOOMode           = HAL_OSPI_SIOO_INST_EVERY_CMD;
       sCommand.Address            = 0;
       sCommand.NbData             = 1;
       /* Memory-mapped mode configuration for Linear burst read operations */
       sCommand.OperationType = HAL_OSPI_OPTYPE_READ_CFG;
       sCommand.Instruction   = OSPI_READ_CMD;
       sCommand.DummyCycles   = 6;

       if (HAL_OSPI_Command(&hospi1, &sCommand, HAL_OSPI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE) != HAL_OK)
       {
        Error_Handler();
       }
       /* Memory-mapped mode configuration for Linear burst write operations */
       sCommand.OperationType = HAL_OSPI_OPTYPE_WRITE_CFG;
       sCommand.Instruction   = OSPI_WRITE_CMD;
       sCommand.DummyCycles   = 0;
       sCommand.DQSMode       = HAL_OSPI_DQS_ENABLE;
       if (HAL_OSPI_Command(&hospi1, &sCommand, HAL_OSPI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE) != HAL_OK)
       {
        Error_Handler();
       }
       /*Disable timeout counter for memory mapped mode*/
       sMemMappedCfg.TimeOutActivation = HAL_OSPI_TIMEOUT_COUNTER_DISABLE;
       /*Enable memory mapped mode*/
       if (HAL_OSPI_MemoryMapped(&hospi1, &sMemMappedCfg) != HAL_OK)
      {
        Error_Handler();
       }


  while (1)
  {

        switch(step)
        {
        case 0:     //WAIT FOR BUTTON PRESSED
            if (HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(B1_GPIO_Port, B1_Pin) == GPIO_PIN_SET)
            {
                step++;
            }
            break;
        case 1:     //WAIT FOR BUTTON RELEASED
            if (HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(B1_GPIO_Port, B1_Pin) == GPIO_PIN_RESET)
            {
                HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED_YELLOW_GPIO_Port, LED_YELLOW_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
                HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED_RED_GPIO_Port, LED_RED_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
                step++;

            }
            break;
        case 2:     //WRITE PSRAM

              for (index = 0; index < 128; index++)

                  buffer[index] = (uint8_t)index;

            mem_addr = (__IO uint8_t *)(OCTOSPI1_BASE + address);
            for (index = 0; index < 128; index++)
            {
                *mem_addr = buffer[index];
                mem_addr++;
            }
            step++;
            break;
        case 3:     //VERIFY PSRAM


            mem_addr = (__IO uint8_t *)(OCTOSPI1_BASE + address);
            for (index = 0; index < 128; index++)
            {
              dato = *mem_addr;
              if (dato != buffer[index])
              {
                  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED_RED_GPIO_Port, LED_RED_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
              }
              mem_addr++;
            }

            HAL_Delay(50);
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED_YELLOW_GPIO_Port, LED_YELLOW_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
            address += 1024;
            if (address >= 8388607)
                address = 0;
            step = 0;
            break;
        default :
          Error_Handler();
        }
  }


}


void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_CRSInitTypeDef RCC_CRSInitStruct = {0};

  /** Supply configuration update enable
  */
  HAL_PWREx_ConfigSupply(PWR_LDO_SUPPLY);
  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
  */
  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE3);

  while(!__HAL_PWR_GET_FLAG(PWR_FLAG_VOSRDY)) {}
  /** Configure LSE Drive Capability
  */
  HAL_PWR_EnableBkUpAccess();
  __HAL_RCC_LSEDRIVE_CONFIG(RCC_LSEDRIVE_LOW);
  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI48|RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI
                              |RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_LSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.LSEState = RCC_LSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_DIV1;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSI48State = RCC_HSI48_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 4;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 16;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = 2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 32;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLR = 2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLRGE = RCC_PLL1VCIRANGE_3;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLVCOSEL = RCC_PLL1VCOWIDE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLFRACN = 0;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_D3PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_D1PCLK1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV8;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB3CLKDivider = RCC_APB3_DIV2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_APB1_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_APB2_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB4CLKDivider = RCC_APB4_DIV2;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Enable the SYSCFG APB clock
  */
  __HAL_RCC_CRS_CLK_ENABLE();
  /** Configures CRS
  */
  RCC_CRSInitStruct.Prescaler = RCC_CRS_SYNC_DIV1;
  RCC_CRSInitStruct.Source = RCC_CRS_SYNC_SOURCE_LSE;
  RCC_CRSInitStruct.Polarity = RCC_CRS_SYNC_POLARITY_RISING;
  RCC_CRSInitStruct.ReloadValue = __HAL_RCC_CRS_RELOADVALUE_CALCULATE(48000000,32768);
  RCC_CRSInitStruct.ErrorLimitValue = 34;
  RCC_CRSInitStruct.HSI48CalibrationValue = 32;

  HAL_RCCEx_CRSConfig(&RCC_CRSInitStruct);
}


static void MX_OCTOSPI1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN OCTOSPI1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END OCTOSPI1_Init 0 */

  OSPIM_CfgTypeDef sOspiManagerCfg = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN OCTOSPI1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END OCTOSPI1_Init 1 */
  /* OCTOSPI1 parameter configuration*/
  hospi1.Instance = OCTOSPI1;
  hospi1.Init.FifoThreshold = 1;
  hospi1.Init.DualQuad = HAL_OSPI_DUALQUAD_DISABLE;
  hospi1.Init.MemoryType = HAL_OSPI_MEMTYPE_APMEMORY;
  hospi1.Init.DeviceSize = 22;
  hospi1.Init.ChipSelectHighTime = 2;
  hospi1.Init.FreeRunningClock = HAL_OSPI_FREERUNCLK_DISABLE;
  hospi1.Init.ClockMode = HAL_OSPI_CLOCK_MODE_0;
  hospi1.Init.WrapSize = HAL_OSPI_WRAP_NOT_SUPPORTED;
  hospi1.Init.ClockPrescaler = 2;
  hospi1.Init.SampleShifting = HAL_OSPI_SAMPLE_SHIFTING_HALFCYCLE;
  hospi1.Init.DelayHoldQuarterCycle = HAL_OSPI_DHQC_DISABLE;
  hospi1.Init.ChipSelectBoundary = 0;
  hospi1.Init.ClkChipSelectHighTime = 0;
  hospi1.Init.DelayBlockBypass = HAL_OSPI_DELAY_BLOCK_BYPASSED;
  hospi1.Init.MaxTran = 0;
  hospi1.Init.Refresh = 0;
  if (HAL_OSPI_Init(&hospi1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sOspiManagerCfg.ClkPort = 1;
  sOspiManagerCfg.NCSPort = 1;
  sOspiManagerCfg.IOLowPort = HAL_OSPIM_IOPORT_1_LOW;
  if (HAL_OSPIM_Config(&hospi1, &sOspiManagerCfg, HAL_OSPI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN OCTOSPI1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END OCTOSPI1_Init 2 */

}


static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOE_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOG_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED_RED_GPIO_Port, LED_RED_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_10, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED_YELLOW_GPIO_Port, LED_YELLOW_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : B1_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = B1_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(B1_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : LED_RED_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = LED_RED_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(LED_RED_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PD10 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_10;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : USB_FS_OVCR_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = USB_FS_OVCR_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_IT_RISING;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(USB_FS_OVCR_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : LED_YELLOW_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = LED_YELLOW_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(LED_YELLOW_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}


void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  __disable_irq();
  while (1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT

void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{

}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */
```

Best Regards,

Mattia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that QSPI module in STM32H72x/3x has **limitations** on memory-mapped write. Basically, the write works only in indirect mode.

Source: https://community.st.com/s/question/0D53W00000V23po/using-quadspi-psram-with-a-stm32h7-is-that-possible-and-wise-performancewise